# Query "can I login as" for users

Tags: api, user-management

Is there an API or other technique to understand whether the current user has been granted access to "login as" another given user?

...other than optimistically trying?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is, unfortunately, but perhaps someone might have a solution I'm not aware of.

Answer (score -1):

According to Salesforce help, the only permission needed to log in as another user is **`Modify All Data`**.

> ### [Log In as Another User](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=logging_in_as_another_user.htm&type=5)
>
> To assist other users, administrators can log in to Salesforce as another user. Depending on your organization settings, individual users might need to grant login access to administrators.
>
> ---
>
> USER PERMISSIONS NEEDED
>   To log in as another user:  Modify All Data
>
> ---

You can determine if the running user has this permission as follows:

```
Boolean hasModifyAllDataPermission = 0 < [
    SELECT count() FROM PermissionSetAssignment
    WHERE AssigneeId = :UserInfo.getUserId()
    AND PermissionSet.PermissionsModifyAllData = true
];
```

Comment: Thanks, however, that's not exactly what I'm asking for. This will might allow me to understand if a user has the potential to "login as another user", but it doesn't tell me if another given user has "granted login access" to local admin/global setting to login as other users has been enabled.